# Getting a "Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference" error in my KRL code

Tags: krl

When I run my Kynetx app I am getting the following error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /web/lib/perl/Kynetx/Persistence.pm line 284, <GEN0> line 465.
```

My code looks like the following:

```
rule page_loaded is active {
  select when pageview "manticore.*" setting()
  pre {
    savedName = current ent:userName;
  }
  if (savedName neq "") then {
    notify("Hello #{savedName}!!","Welcome back!") with sticky = true;
  }
  notfired {
    raise explicit event name_not_saved_yet;
  }  
}
```

I had this code working before, not sure what is killing it now.

**UPDATE:**
From the debug information.

```
// 2010/12/07 16:45:31 DEBUG Scheduler.pm a57x4 clear_saved_name Schedule iterator returning email_client with current RID count 0 and current rule count 3
// 2010/12/07 16:45:31 DEBUG Rules.pm a57x4 email_client Rule email_client is active
// 2010/12/07 16:45:31 DEBUG Rules.pm a57x4 email_client [selected] email_client
// 2010/12/07 16:45:31 DEBUG Rules.pm a57x4 email_client
//------------------- begin rule execution: email_client ------------------------
// 2010/12/07 16:45:31 ERROR Rules.pm a57x4 email_client Ruleset a57x4 failed: Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /web/lib/perl/Kynetx/Persistence.pm line 284, <GEN0> line 6.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We changed the way that we store trails.  I will put a bug fix in asap.

If I show you some secret functionality, you need to promise not to tell

for your entity variable try the syntax (if you have a variable myUserName):

```
 set ent:userName myUserName
```

Then, for your example, you could write:

```
pre {
  savedName = ent:userName || "";
}
if (savedName neq "") then ....
```

I will update this answer when we release a fix

Comment: current was dying on an empty trail.  Fix (fb1314) is going to QA for testing and should release this evening